# Every node in graph must have only 6 neighbors using R

Tags: r, networkx, igraph, sna

I have a random graph of 10 nodes (possibly there can be more than 1000 nodes). I have write the following code.

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10,1,type = "gnp",directed = FALSE)
degree(g)
[1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

The network diagram is as follows. 
[image]

Now, I want to make a change that every node must have 6 degree. Put simply, Degree of every node must be 6, neither more than 6 nor less than 6.

Comment: in `igraph` you can generate random graphs with given degree using `sample_degseq` https://igraph.org/r/doc/sample_degseq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)
g = sample_degseq(out.deg = rep(6,10), method = "simple.no.multiple")
degree(g)
[1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Here, What does mean by Set.seed(1234)

Comment: is this graph would be connected?

Comment: I used `set.seed` so that the example would be reproducible. `sample_degseq` generates random numbers and without `set.seed`  you would get a different answer than the one that I got.. With 10 nodes and degree 6, yes, the graph must be connected. However, with other combinations of numbers there is no guarantee of connectivity.

Comment: I have to make a graph with 4000 nodes and every node must have 6 neighbors. Can I do this for above code?

Comment: If you change the 10 in the above code to 4000, it will work.  After running the above code,  run  `table(components(g)$membership)` to see that there is a single component. Technically, it is possible that it could have more than one component, but the probability of that happening is _very small_.